# Pyperclip is giving an error

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyperclip

I use python 2.7. I installed pyperclip using `sudo pip install pyperclip` and it was installed successfully.

Every time I use the following simple code

```
import pyperclip
pyperclip.copy('Hello World')
message=pyperclip.paste()
print (message)
```

I get the following error:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:57:
GtkWarning: could not open display   warnings.warn(str(e),
_gtk.Warning) /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyperclip/__init__.py:102:
GtkWarning: IA__gtk_clipboard_get_for_display: assertion 'display !=
NULL' failed   cb = gtk.Clipboard() Traceback (most recent call last):
File "first.py", line 401, in <module>
    pyperclip.copy('Hello World')   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyperclip/__init__.py", line
102, in _copyGtk
    cb = gtk.Clipboard() RuntimeError: could not create GtkClipboard object
```

Comment: Don't use `sudo pip`; either use a virtualenv or `pip install --user`.

Comment: Do you have pygtk installed?

Answer (score 8):

It always helps to read the documentation.

> ```
> On Windows, no additional modules are needed.
> ```

```
On Mac, the module uses pbcopy and pbpaste, which should come with the os.
On Linux, install xclip or xsel via package manager. For example, in Debian:
sudo apt-get install xclip
```

> Otherwise on Linux, you will need the gtk or PyQt4 modules installed.

> gtk and PyQt4 modules are not available for Python 3,
> and this module does not work with PyGObject yet.

So all you need to do at your terminal is `sudo apt install xclip`  and then the gtk and PyQt4 modules via pip (for python 2).

Answer (score 3):

When using Python3 on a Debian based system, please install xclip and pyqt4 as the documentation states.

```
sudo apt-get install xclip python3-pyqt4
```

Then you can easily copy DataFrames like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sys

dates = pd.date_range('20130101',periods=6)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,4),index=dates,columns=list('ABCD'))

df.to_clipboard()
```

Pasting works with Google Sheets or Excel.

Answer (score 1):

None of these work on ubuntu server - 16.04.
Reason being ubuntu server does not have a GUI.
Reference link : https://www.thetopsites.net/article/51662213.shtml