# Python / GTK error when trying to use pyperclip.copy() in Debian 9

Tags: python, python-3.x, debian, xfce, pyperclip

I'm a complete novice in programming, I've searched the bellow error in google in different ways but without luck of finding reasonable results.

My code is basically trying to:

```
pyperclip.copy(str(DICTIONARY[KEY]))
```

My invocation of the program in the command line is:

```
python3 ./PasswordManager.py blog
```

Where "blog" is the "key" of the above function.

And these are the errors I'm receiving:

```
(python3:26893): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:186:14: Expected a string.

(python3:26893): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:2749:24: not a number

(python3:26893): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:2749:24: Expected a string.

(python3:26893): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:2940:14: not a number

(python3:26893): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:2940:14: Expected a string.

(python3:26893): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:2946:17: Expected a string.

(python3:26893): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:4083:14: not a number

(python3:26893): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:4083:14: Expected a string.

(python3:26893): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:4088:17: Expected a string.

(python3:26893): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:4729:14: not a number

(python3:26893): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:4729:14: Expected a string.

(python3:26893): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: xfce.css:47:16: not a number

(python3:26893): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: xfce.css:47:16: Expected a string.

(python3:26893): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: lightdm-gtk-greeter.css:16:14: not a number

(python3:26893): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: lightdm-gtk-greeter.css:16:14: Expected a string.

(python3:26893): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: lightdm-gtk-greeter.css:26:14: not a number

(python3:26893): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: lightdm-gtk-greeter.css:26:14: Expected a string.

(python3:26893): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: lightdm-gtk-greeter.css:40:16: not a number

(python3:26893): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: lightdm-gtk-greeter.css:40:16: Expected a string.

(python3:26893): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: lightdm-gtk-greeter.css:96:14: Expected a string.

(python3:26893): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: lightdm-gtk-greeter.css:100:16: not a number

(python3:26893): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: lightdm-gtk-greeter.css:100:16: Expected a string.

(python3:26893): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: lightdm-gtk-greeter.css:279:14: not a number

(python3:26893): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: lightdm-gtk-greeter.css:279:14: Expected a string.
```

Comment: These are just warnings which can be ignored. Did your program work as expected?

Comment: No, the program was meant to copy the dictionary value for that key into my clipboard, which is actually empty.

Comment: @MichaelButscher I found the answer in another question here. Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was completely solved by

```
sudo apt-get install xclip xsel
```

Source: [Pyperclip is giving an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32163481/pyperclip-is-giving-an-error)